# Drupal 7 cron runs indefinitely

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, cron, drupal-7

I can't setup drupal's cron to run, because it runs indefinitely. It is strange, before it worked well. Moreover, I installed cron_debug, and with this module it runs in 19 sec and report success for all modules, but if I do 'drush cron' or 'run cron' button in web interface - it never stops.

I have latest drupal 7 updated with bunch of modules, running on nginx and php7-fpm.

I don't understand why cron_debug runs ok, but usual cron is freezing. 
I followed most advises from here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron/troubleshooting-cron  but they did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed elysia-cron, and it showed, that stuck was with bounce module. I have reinstalled this module and all went fine. I'll keep using this module, because it is awesome.

Comment: take care about elysia cron , it create a queue and can run cron more later than is configured if a lot of cron take a lot of time, if you want more precision set you cron into crontab linux with external script exectued

Comment: I just added 'drush elysia-cron run' to my crontab and it is working fine

Comment: Because you don't have a lot of active cron , with a huge quantity of cron elysia make delay to execute all of them , it's just good to know  ;)